# How do I store data in members of multiple classes from an ifstream in a separate class?

Tags: c++, file, oop, stream, ifstream

I am currently leaning C++ though I am having troubles understanding how to implement object orientation style of program with in and out file streams. I have made a program using operation overloading methods as friend classes though apparently this is bad practice as it breaches the privacy of the class.

For some context I need to make a program for reading in a csv file with student name, id, grade date etc. The reading in of this file would go in a registration class i'd assume. The registration would have a member ifstream infile; and the name of the file specified in a constructor. This class would then have a function which is where im stuck. I'm attempting to read in the text file and assigning the elements of the file to variables of object instances. For examples, student 1 would have 3 courses/units, each unit would have a grade. Hence I would store 3 results (in a results class) for that one student and then increment to the text student and read their courses and grades. Note: each student and course information is on a single line in file.

Basically my question is how should I attempt to store information from a file stream into objects of another class eg: result class or Course class? What if I needed to store data where the Unit class and even a Date class was a aggregated object of Results class? Originally using sets and gets would be logical but would it be right. I'm not asking for code but more of a best practice for OO and file streams.

Comment: Once the type of the object being stored diverges from a singular fundamental, I hope it is obvious that type-identification in one form or another had better be part of the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is also fiddly - implementing `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Student&)`, responsible for parsing out the data for a student.  Exactly what this would look like is hard to say... presumably student names can be multiple words, potentially with embedded `'` or even `-`.  If `id` is known to contain at least one digit then you could use that to differentiate `id` from `name`.  You can read whitespace-separate tokens with `>>` to a `std::string`, but need to be careful as that will skip over newlines to find the next string, so if you're reading whatever's last on the line and want to stop at a newline you may need to specific the `'\n'` delimiter to `getline` (then remove any other trailing whitespace if you want to be tolerant to accidental padding).  If handling the newline proves too hard you may want to consider having an outer loop that uses `while (getline(input_stream, line))` to read entire lines into `std::string line`, then create `std::istringstream iss(line);` and parse an individual student's data from `iss`... that way you can parse until failure or "EOF" without worrying about newlines.

This approach should be applied hierarchically.  If you want to parse out dates, then create an `operator>>` for your `Date` class.

Sadly, adopting this best practice can be daunting for a learner....